# CURL : Unauthorized 401 error while downloading zip file from Artifactory

Tags: c++, artifactory, libcurl

I am trying to download a zip file from Artifactory using the libcurl library in the below C++ code. But I am getting the following error:

json
{
"errors" : [ {
"status" : 401,
"message" : "Unauthorized"
} ]
}

```
static size_t WriteCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main()
{
   CURL *curl;
   CURLcode res;
   std::string readBuffer;
   FILE *fp;
   const char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "./Users/shrabana/.myOrg/test_media/Test.zip";

   curl = curl_easy_init();

   std::string command = "https://artifactory.corp.myOrg.com/artifactory/generic-test-media/Test.zip";

   if(curl) 
   {         
      fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
           
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, command.c_str());
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "X-JFrog-Art-Api:$ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY -O");
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);

      res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
      curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

      int i = fclose(fp);
      if (i == 0)
          std::cout<<"All is well"<<std::endl;

      system("unzip -j Test.zip");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting `CURLAUTH_BASIC`, you are missing setting `CURLOPT_USERPWD` that is required by the basic http authentication. You are setting the header "X-JFrog-Art-Api". Perhaps `CURLAUTH_BASIC` is odd, and "$ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY" should be replaced with a real value.

Comment: Per the [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API), you are supposed to use EITHER `Basic` authentication OR the `X-JFrog-Art-Api` header, NOT both

Comment: This is generic code , instead of using a password I am using ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY. Through the terminal I am able to download the package using the command: curl -H X-JFrog-Art-Api:$ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY -O https://artifactory.corp.myOrg.com/artifactory/generic-test-media/Test.zip

Comment: Same thing I am trying to automate using code

Comment: Add `--libcurl` to your command: `curl --libcurl -H X-JFrog-Art-Api:$ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY -O https://artifactory.corp.myorg.com/artifactory/generic-test-media/Test.zip`, you will get a code you are looking for.

Comment: The ` -O` should not be part of the header, remove it from this line:
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "X-JFrog-Art-Api:$ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY -O");`

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting 401 error while trying to download a zip file from Artifactory, in order to rule out issues with regards to the authentication/API key, please do try retrieving the artifact from the direct curl/wget command using the direct user password instead of the API.

If you are able to retrieve using the direct password then try regenerating the API key from the user profile page and see if that helps in resolving the reported issue.